# What does the Misleading Trail™ lead to?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

This puzzle aims to test a concept I have. A list of clues is given, each referring to an item, place, idea, or other. Combining each answer with the next clue allows you find the answers in order until you reach the end of the trail.

> **What does the Misleading Trail™ lead to?**
>
> 1. An industry featuring Plumbers and Hedgehogs.
> 2. Motion-controlled speed.
> 3. The french name for the fruit.
> 4. One whose profession is the above.
> 5. The eleventh champion.
> 6. Sixteen a side.
> 7. Can fly.

Comment: This is really very good, nice job!

Comment: @Rubio Thanks! I'm planning on making these semi-regularly, so stay tuned :)

Comment: This puzzle's title adds nothing really (the final clue makes it redundant). As a tip for future puzzles, it would be really nice if the title confirmed a final answer in much the same way that subsequent clues confirm interim answers. For example, "Misleading Trail™" would have been a great title for this one. :)

Comment: Why "Misleading"?

Comment: Your answer has more than 2 meanings.

Comment: @Rubio got you. I went for a non-obvious bird sounding adjective, but I see where you're coming from

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is the answer...

> Rook?

An industry featuring Plumbers and Hedgehogs.

> Two of the most famous characters in **video games** are Mario and Sonic.

Motion-controlled speed.

> A racing video game controlled by motions could be **Mario Kart Wii**.

The french name for the fruit.

> The character named after a fruit is Peach; in French this would be **pecher**.

One whose profession is the above.

> Pecher is also "to fish" in French, so maybe **fisher**?

The eleventh champion.

> The eleventh world champion of chess was **Bobby Fischer**.

Sixteen a side.

> Chess has sixteen **pieces** on each side.

Can fly.

> **Rook** is the name of both a chess piece and a bird, which can fly.

Comment: You scored 6 out of 7 there.

Comment: @AricFowler hmm, probably the last one then. The nice property about this puzzle is that subsequent clues confirm older clues; for instance I had no idea what 6 meant before solving 5. But there'should no confirmation for the last one and I can see a lot of 6s that fly; and no reason to choose one of them. Was Mike right or is it something else?

Comment: Mike was incorrect. Also that is the concept of the puzzle: New answers serve to confirm old ones, in a way.

Comment: @ffao - [ROT47](https://rot47.net/):  9EEADi^^6?]H:<:A65:2]@C8^H:<:^#@@<0W3:C5X